# Understanding CPU Utilisation Graph for a task running AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, cpu-usage

I have a task defined with 0.5vCPU. It has two containers with 0.25vCPU

Can someone explain to me what the below CPU Utilization graph represents?

[image]

The above graph is from Health and Metrics section in AWS Console for the sevice.

Since each of my containers has 0.25 vCPU it is expected that the container gets at most 25% of a CPU core every second. Then what does ~115% (max CPU utilisation) mean in the above graph?

Should not the container be killed when it reaches 100% CPU Utilisation? Why is the max cpu utilisation showing more than 100%?

Comment: This may be more on topic at serberfault.com - but why wpuld a container be killed for maxing outvCPU? I'd expect it just to be limited/cpu bound while the hypervisor gives tome to other vm's.